# Nuxt CDN: How to host JS files?

Tags: nuxt.js, cdn

Nuxt has a default configuration for CDN. You just have to do:

```
// nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  build: {
    publicPath: "https://you-cdn-url.com/_nuxt/"
  }
}
```

But when I go to my console, **the application just gets images from the CDN**. I was hoping it would also load CSS and JS files.

Can I make it work?

(The Nuxt app is SSR)

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue in Nuxt.

After build, the application use relative path to reference the JS files. Instead, it should point to the CDN url.

Ref: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8973.